# Excel formula for cumulative interest rate with variable yearly rates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have large table of year values along with values for that year and corresponding inflation rates for that year:

[image]

For any given period of years - lets say 10 - I'm using VLOOKUP to get the values and want to find the cumulative interest rate for that period so that I can sum the values and apply the cumulative rate.

I did find a formula for Powerpivot which does exactly what I need using SUM and LN but my Excel skills don't stretch to converting it:
[Powerpivot formula](https://powerpivotpro.com/2013/11/cumulative-interest-or-inflation-multiplying-every-value-in-a-column-why-dont-we-have-productx/)

Can anyone assist here please?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Excel contains `LN` function and `EXP` function (like PowerPivot) -- but the PowerPivot article only uses them as a workaround (since the article says there was no `PRODUCTX` function in PowerPivot). Can you provide a worked example of what you're trying to achieve? To me it seems like you just want the `PRODUCT` function in Excel to multiply the values in column C. If the values need to be conditionally selected, then maybe PRODUCT in an array formula. But I'm not sure what you're after.

Comment: Excel doesn't contain PRODUCTX either, or equivalent. It's pretty simple what I'm after - in the above example: Select a range of values from column B via VLOOKUP on column A, SUM those values from B then apply the cumulative interest rate of the corresponding values in C to that sum.

Comment: e.g. Select a range of values (e.g.2005-2010) from column B via VLOOKUP on column A, SUM those values from B then apply the cumulative interest rate of the corresponding values in C to that sum. The below example achieves this, but only by adding more columns and hard coding therefore I couldn;t find these values by selecting ANY group of 10 (e.g. 2008-2013) from the listbecause the cumulative is applied to fro the first year, not the first year I requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can Achieve that with Simple Excel Formulas:

[image]

Comment: Correct, however I was trying to avoid a table. so that using VLOOKUP I can query the table, sum the values and multiplty that total by the final cumulative value easily. Seems like without the Excel data addin it's not possible, thanks.